# Print Pie Chart percentages in Matlab in Rational Format

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, pie-chart

In the Matlab Pie Chart, in categorical data, the results are printed in percentage format.
Is there any way to change this format in rational form? E.g. instead of 50% in a set of 12 data, to print 6/12 instead. Typing format long in the workspace does not solve this.

Even better, can we write both results, i.e. 50% (6/12).

Working example:

```
X = categorical({'North','South','North','East','South','West'});
pie(X)
```

[image: pie chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `countcats` to get the number of occurrences and make the labels manually:

```
N = numel(X);         % total number of items
n = countcats(X);     % number of items per category
cats = categories(X); % unique categories in same order as countcats
labels = arrayfun( @(ii) sprintf('%s (%.0f/%.0f)', cats{ii}, n(ii), N), ...
                   1:numel(n), 'uni', 0 );
```

Then make your pie chart

```
pie(n, labels)
```